# Why do questions vanish from the new reopen review queues?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen

As mentioned in the comments on this question about one bug with the new reopen reviews...

I saw this happen a couple days in a row on Serverfault but didn't get screen shots, today it happened on SciFi:

When I started reviewing, it showed a lot of questions waiting to be reviewed, but as I did a few reviews, the # waiting plumetted.  What happened to the other questions?

At first there were 43 needing review:

[image]

I reviewed 2, got a message "Sorry there are no more items for you to review" and it showed 20 needing review:

[image]

I refreshed a couple times, was able to review 2 more, and then there were none:

[image]

Comment: What happened? They got reviewed. By others.

Comment: Then why don't those reviews by others show up in the counts?

Comment: @Oded And when?  SciFi's not that active, I don't really think 39 questions were co-incidently reviewed at the same time I was doing reviews.

Comment: OK. I'm convinced...

Comment: On a related note, this morning I saw 42 questions in the Reopen Queueueueueueueueue on SF get cleared with a total of 8 reviews.

Comment: Happened to me on Drupal Answers. Almost 80 review tasks, most of them suddenly gone.

Comment: Confirmed on Web Apps. _Just_ entered reopen queue with advertised 30 questions, reviewed 7, and now there are none to review. No one else was active in that queue during that time, and all of the other queues were empty.

Comment: And now on Android. 30 questions advertised for the reopen queue. Acted on 10. Now suddenly empty. So, something's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with the queries fetching and invalidating the reopen queue items.

This has now been resolved.

Comment: Will those "lost" queue items find their way back to the queue?

Comment: @AlEverett - They have. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196697/review-reopen-post-queue-suddenly-increase

Comment: And other sites in the network?

Comment: @AlEverett - yes. I have seen others reporting the reopen queue going crazy.

Comment: Egg salad. I'll keep an eye out.