# Review reopen post queue suddenly increase

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-reopen

I usually observe other than close votes all review queue has small numbers but today reopen post also have 3 figure number. Is queue was blocked due to some bug?

> [image: reopen]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest build fixed a long-standing bug in the Reopen Queue (~500 questions), as well as adding a few hundred "popularly" closed questions for your attention.

Popularity in this case means lots of views plus a great question score plus a great average answer score - the community team will be tweaking these values in the coming days and will discuss them.