# Skipping Questions X Times

Tags: discussion, review

I've been reviewing questions for a while now but just recently I've come across several situations where the questions asked (sometimes answers) is just not something I feel comfortable enough with to accept/deny so instead I choose to `Skip` and move on.

In this situation I can see there are currently 30 `First Posts` up for review. The first three questions follow the situation I just explained and now all of a sudden there are no more `First Posts` to review. I highly doubt that all 30 reviews happened within the first 15 seconds (I'm sure it's possible though).

So it seems if you `Skip` X number of times then you are somehow excluded from reviewing the remaining items still in queue.

Specifically I only review on StackOverflow.com and there are hundreds of categories which can be put into review for this site and we can't be expected to understand every category that passes into the Review area.

I feel we shouldn't be penalized for skipping if we really don't know the information being passed. Instead we should be able to continue reviewing in hopes that something that does spark our general intelligence shows up.

Comment: There have been some bugs in the past with the review queue count being off, such as audit posts of other users counting in the review size.  Odds are there were only 3 (or close to three) posts in the queue right from the start.  You skipping post almost certainly didn't result in other posts being skipped.

Comment: @Servy I'd guess that it was pretty close to 30. The First Posts queue only allows one person to view an item at a time, so it's not a matter of all the reviews actually happening within 15 seconds, just that they were all handed out for review quickly. The Late Answers queue works similarly.

Comment: See also: [Why do questions vanish from the new reopen review queues?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196609)

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for future situations. As a test I continued to refresh the page until I noticed a queue (this time was 18). As soon as I opened the first review and clicked next, the queue was magically empty. This time it was only a matter of probably 2 seconds between the time the queue showed, clicked to review, skipped, and refreshed. Something just doesn't seem right about this...

Comment: I was just about to post a similar question when I saw this one.  I too will sometimes see 25-50 items in the review queue... I'll skip 2-3 edits that I don't feel qualified for and then the queue is empty. I'd agree with @Servy that it ins't a result of my actions but it never seems to happen when I accept/reject edits... only if I skip.

Comment: Happening again, this time there was 34 in queue, I skipped the first two after a matter of maybe 5 seconds as I had no idea about the topic, and the queue was empty.

Comment: 30 in queue, skipped the first one, queue was empty after that.

Comment: Is this still happening?